# How to change the behaviour of a method at runtime?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

Short Version:

The main point is that the (complex) state of an instance can be changed by functions that are outside the definition of the class, as such the class can be extended to have all sorts of internal states without polluting the class defintion with many state-setters.

Assume the following code:

```
 class bar
 {
      virtual void ChangeState()=0;
 }
 class foo:bar
 {
 private:
      int b;
 public:
      void ChangeState() {b=3;}
 }
```

What I would like to do is create different functions, then pass them to the function, at runtime, something like

```
foo.ChangeState(); //b is 3 now
void foo::(?)ChangeState2(){ b=2; };
foo.ChangeState=ChangeState2;
foo.ChangeState(); //b is 2 now
```

Can such a construct be implemented in C++, without the use of hacks?

Comment: There is no way that you can change a function in C++ at runtime [within the definition of the language, clearly if you can find the right address in memory, and make the memory writeable, you can write new instructions to the memory].

Comment: @MatsPetersson: You can however, change a function _pointer_

Comment: @Mooing Duck: Obviously, yes. That is one option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe, this will help:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace so
{

class B
{
  friend void change_1( B * );
  friend void change_2( B * );
  friend void change_3( B * );

  int i;
 public:
  B() : i{ 0 } {}

  void change_state( void (*_function)( B * ) )
  {
   _function( this );

   std::cout << i << std::endl;
  }
};

void change_1( B * _object )
{
 _object->i = -1;
}
void change_2( B * _object )
{
 _object->i = -2;
}
void change_3( B * _object )
{
 _object->i = -3;
}

} //namespace so

int main()
{
 so::B b{ };

 b.change_state( so::change_1 );
 b.change_state( so::change_2 );
 b.change_state( so::change_3 );

 return( 0 );
}
```

Comment: That's [similarish to what I came up with](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=2374eff4521ef575b7c21854a02662a0-c96156d6cc95286981b0e9deef2eefae)

Comment: @MooingDuck +1 I would say both ways are essentially the same. In fact, making functions `static` gives it more logical coupling to the class. But I have to say, I think the OP is asking a wrong question. I think, he should be asking "what would be a smooth design for a class with a lot of data-members that need to be 'set/get'?".

Comment: @PetrBudnik You are correct, maybe I should post another question.

Comment: @Taikand I humbly suggest you search SO first because it was discussed before - setters/getters. However, if you feel you are not satisfied with what you find, then make a new post. Such questions are usually interesting with people sharing their views on and experience in general design patterns/tricks/idioms.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: That's not possible.

What you can do is define multiple classes and choose between them based on some runtime condition. And of course, that object doesn't have to be the full class, we could do something like this:

```
 class foo: public bar
 {
    private:
       class ChangeState
       {
         public:
           virtual void DoChangeState(foo *f) = 0;
       };
       class ChangeState2
       {
         public:
           virtual void DoChangeState(foo *f) { f->b = 2 } ;
       };
       class ChangeState3 : public ChangeState
       { 
         public:
           virtual void DoChangeState(foo *f) { f->b = 3 } ;
       };
   ChangeState *stateChanger

   public:
      foo() { stateChanger = new ChangeState3; }
      void SetStateChange2() { delete stateChanger; stateChanger = new ChangeState2; }
      ~foo() { delete stateChanger; }
      void ChangeState() { stateChanger->DoChangeState(this); }
};
```

I'm sure there are other variations on this theme (and you probably should use a smart pointer).

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the behaviour at runtime using the syntax you describe. You can however if you wish get something similar by using function pointers.

But if I understand what you are trying to accomplish correctly, I would look at implementing the [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)